# How to retrieve objects from rest url with multiple parameters using angular

Tags: angularjs

How can i create a factory that can retrieve data from 
/rest/company/:companyid/employee/:id

when i use this url in the factory I get an error: Unknown provider companyidProvider

Thank you,

Kyle

Service:

```js
app.factory('EmployeeByCompany', function ($resource,companyid) { 
    return $resource('app/rest/company/:companyid/employee/:id', {}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
        'get': { method: 'GET'}
    });
});
```

I'm guessing the error is from having the companyid as a parameter with $resource. What is the right way for a service to call this url?

Comment: Post more code of how you are doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are learning or geting started, try Restangular https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer because it does work. I just have to believe there is another way to fill in that :companyid variable.